# 2021 Community Moderator Election

Tags: discussion, moderators, election

The 2021 Community Moderator Election is now underway!

Community moderator elections have three phases:

1. Nomination phase
2. Primary phase
3. Election phase

Most elections take between two and three weeks, but this depends on how many candidates there are.

Please visit the official election page at

https://math.stackexchange.com/election

for more detail, and to participate!

If you have general questions about the election process, or questions for moderator candidates, feel free to ask them here on meta -- just make sure your questions are tagged [election](/questions/tagged/election).

Comment: What counts as an answer in this thread?  No link to the official questionnaire, no link to the official nomination phase.     Not good to have too many open meta posts  that only contain links elsewhere.

Comment: @amWhy I think it's all in one now, the [election page](https://math.stackexchange.com/election?cb=1) contains the 10 questions (Show questions) and the nomination posts will include answers.

Comment: The link is to the question collection post, which should now be closed.  My browser is acting up lately, and there's no reason I should need to open five tabs at a time to follow this election.

Comment: @TheSimpliFire  so candidates must go both and forth to two posts to copy and past questions, and then answer them, in their nomination post?  Usually, in the past, Candidates would announce their candidacy; they'd be expected to answer on another page listing, oldest to newest, each candidate's responses to the questions.  The chosen questions would be in "the question field", and candidates would be able to each answer the posted questions on that page, so overall, users could see the questions, and candidate answers, all posted in one locale.

Comment: I think this confusion is all the more reason to leave a day between question collection and nominations, and between nominations and elections, so each new CM overseeing the election can have time to get their act together, prior to creating links that aren't yet active.

Comment: @amWhy I believe that when you create/edit your nomination post the questionnaire is pre-loaded in the text editor. See [Moderator Elections: new questionnaire UI](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/362933/986753) on [metase].

Comment: The above is correct, clicking on "nominate yourself as a candidate" takes me to a page with [prefilled input boxes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0IxjV.png) (curiously, it uses the new markdown editor)