# Implementing a fill-in-the-blank type structure for new users asking questions

Tags: discussion, feature-request, asking-questions, new-users

A notable problem on this site seems to be [PSQ](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33854/1072645)s from new users. In order to encourage better questions, I suggest implementing a fill-in-the-blank type structure for new users asking questions. Once a certain reputation is achieved (for example, 150), the system can revert back to the standard question interface. The following is a rough sketch of what the new user interface may look like:

---

**Title**
Make your title your question; use it to convey as much information as possible. Don't be afraid to make it long.
*[Space to add title]*

**Question Statement**
Write the statement of the question, including all assumptions and conditions. This may be the same as the title.
*[Space to add question statement]*

**Source/Motivation**
Mention where you came across the question and/or what prompted you to ask about it.
*[Space to add source/motivation]*

**Background (optional)**
Indicate your level of familiarity with the question topic.
*[Space to add background]*

**Definitions (optional)**
Define any important terms relating to the question.
*[Space to add definitions]*

**Your Work**
Include your thoughts, observations, research and/or attempts to solve the problem.
*[Space to add the OP's work]*

**Other (optional)**
Add any additional details relevant to the question.
*[Space to add other details]*

**References (optional)**
Link any references appropriate to the question.
*[Space to add references]*

**Tags**
Add up to 5 tags to describe what your question is about.
*[Space to add tags]*

---

The question can then render as follows:

$\large\text{[Title]}$

> [Question Statement]

### Source/Motivation

[Source/Motivation]

### Background

[Background]

etc.

---

After the question has been posted, the OP can edit the question using the standard interface, thus being able to reformat and restructure the question if necessary.

Happy to hear feedback on the same.

Comment: Perhaps not exactly the same, but this suggestion seems a bit similar: [Will this site add a guided mode similar to the one recently introduced on Stack Overflow?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/30528) There are some older posts on this topic, too: [Should M.SE consider a Question Wizard Guide?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9640) and [Could "Ask Question" dialog be more helpful?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/8720) (I won't be surprised if you find some other related discussions here on this meta.)

Comment: @MartinSleziak Thanks for sharing. Nonetheless, I feel like the answers to the cited questions do not satisfactorily answer the question. Considering that those posts are pretty old, I think it makes sense to revisit the discussion.

Comment: If implemented, this template suggestion will definitely yield desired results (and possibly have monotony as a side effect). Unfortunately, I don't forsee StackExchange making such a change (or even the simpler-to-implement [single-line homepage notice](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/34923/21813)  pointing to [such a table](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/34067/21813)) for this site without concerted, tremendous advocacy (and not here, but on the main Meta site).

Comment: I like this idea and I think for now this would at least be helpful as part of either [How to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question) or [Is there a shorter and more opinionated version of "How to ask a good question?" that we can direct new users to?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/34059/is-there-a-shorter-and-more-opinionated-version-of-how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: I'm a bit of a grump who suspects that "do my homework" new users won't be deterred by anything, but I think this is actually a good idea. The requested info is the stuff people end up having to ask for after a question is posted; why not ask beforehand. As a grump, l don't have high hopes for SE implementing it, but +1 and a thumbs up for nice thinking.

Comment: I just want to point out: **The Technology Is Here, Or At Least Over There**: there were pre-filled boxes in the 2021 moderator elections. I have [a screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0IxjV.png). ( It is from [this comment of mine.](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/34271/2021-community-moderator-election#comment158631_34271) ) Since the new editor is being worked on, it might be a good idea to suggest this properly on the main Meta.SE site, if it hasn't been done

Comment: @CalvinKhor Now asked [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/380502/1218938).

Comment: This is a neat idea. Certainly the current strategies of linking to [How to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question) seems to have limited effect. Not that it's a personal priority, but I feel compelled to point out that this will negatively affect one of MSE's dual priorities: in particular, being a Q&A repository. This level of detail, while it will be great for responding to the individual asker, it will probably also make questions cluttered and more difficult to read/search for, especially for elementary users.